# Mazur-Ulam bases in finite-dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, group-actions

**Definition.** A basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of a finite-dimensional Banach space $X$ is called *Mazur-Ulam* if all vectors $e_1,\dots,e_n$ have norm one and every self-isometry $f:S_X\to S_X$ of the unit sphere $S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ that does not move the basic vectors is the identity map of $S_X$. Banach spaces are considered over the field of real numbers.

> **Problem 1.** Has every finite-dimensional Banach space a Mazur-Ulam basis?
>
> **Problem 2.** Is every basis in a finite-dimensional Banach space a Mazur-Ulam basis?

---

This problem was posed on 30 March 2021 by Taras Banakh on [page 63](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=63) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize.** A ticket to Lviv Opera Theater.

---

**Remark 1.** The answer to Problem 2 (resp. 1) is affirmative for Banach spaces of dimension $\le 2$ (resp. $\le 3$).

**Remark 2.** This problem is a partial case of a more general (still unsolved) [Tingley's problem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00147942) asking whether every bijective isometry between the unit spheres of two Banach spaces extends to a linear isometry of the Banach spaces.